# Get UIImage from UIImageView with masked subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, mask

Through Face Detection, I want to blur eyes and mouth of a person. So I have a imageView that contains 3 subviews (2 per eye and the mouth). Each one of these subviews were masked with a PNG shape (with background clear) for avoiding to show rectangle.
My imageView in screen remain so: http://screencast.com/t/ak4SkNXM0I

And  I want to obtain the image for storing in another place, so I've tried this:

```
CGSize size = [imageView bounds].size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[[imageView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But finalImage is an image like this:

http://screencast.com/t/eDlvGqqY

My subViews (eyes and mouth) are not masked as above.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have to use library compatible with ios6

Answer (score 0):

You can check the new [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates%3a) added to iOS7. Try one of the following methods:

- `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`
- `resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets:` for resizable image
- `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my App should be made for iOS6 :(